# jquery.tree.checkbox.js not working properly in ie9

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, cross-browser, treeview, internet-explorer-9

I am using MVC 2, for treeview i am using jquery.tree.checkbox.js plugin. It is working fine in mozilla 3.6+ but in IE9 tree view is not working properly. The data is not loading properly in IE9. 
I had used the code 
`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9" />` for IE compatible.
 Is there any solution?

Please somebody help me? NO reply for this question from one week. I am waiting for it :(